# How do I calculate the partials of ECEF coordinates with respect to Geodetic coordinates?

Tags: partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, geodesy

This question could possibly be posted in a different forum but I think the crux of the issue is an incorrect mathematical derivation.

This [Wikipedia website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates) provides equations for converting from ECEF to Geodetic coordinates. When I compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial\phi}$ at the equator, I'm getting a very large value: 6335439.327292461 meters per degree latitude, but I expect something more along the lines of 111,000 meters per degree latitude.

I'm starting with
$$
z(\phi) = \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}N(\phi) + h\right)\sin(\phi)
$$
where $b$ is the polar radius of the Earth, $a$ is the equatorial radius of the Earth, $N$ is the prime vertical radius of curvature, and $\phi$ is latitude.

The equation I'm using for $N$ is
$$
N = \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\phi) + b^2\sin^2(\phi)}}
$$

And here's how I've computed the partial:
$$
\frac{\partial z(\phi)}{\partial \phi} = \frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac{\partial N(\phi)}{\partial \phi}\sin(\phi) + \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}N(\phi) + h\right)\cos(\phi)
$$
with
$$
\frac{\partial N(\phi)}{\partial \phi} = \frac{N^3}{a^4}(a^2-b^2)\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)
$$

Evaluating this at $\phi=0$ yields:
$$
\frac{\partial N(\phi)}{\partial \phi}\Bigg|_{\phi=0} = \frac{b^2}{a^2}N(0\phi) + h
$$
which is roughly the value I have listed.

Did I compute $\frac{\partial N(\phi)}{\partial \phi}$ incorrectly? Or am I interpreting the partial incorrectly? I thought it should tell me the meter change per degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting meters per *radian* longitude, instead of degree? That figure of 6.3 million meters seems to be about right for that (because it's pretty close to the Earth's radius.) If you multiply your figure by $\pi/180$, you get 110,574.3 m, which seems close to what you were expecting.

Comment: Of course! Since latitude input into the cosine is in radians, I either need to convert to degrees before taking the partial or get a partial that is meters/radian.